# Users can edit anything when I use a VF page as an Edit override

Tags: visualforce, security, master-detail, access

I want to allow my users to only edit records they own with two objects which are in a Master/Detail setup.

I have the following setup :

Master Object :
OWD : Public Read Only
User's Permission Set for Object : Read, Create, Edit

Detail Object : 
OWD : Controlled by Parent
User's Permission Set for Object : Read, Create, Edit

This is working fine until I use a VF page I have made as the Edit Override in the Detail object. Users can only edit records they own.

I am using a VF page as the Edit override on the Detail object. I am not overriding the View for the object. When I use the VF page users can edit any of the detail records, including ones they don't own - and even ones which are locked !

The VF page is nothing special. Here it is :

```
        <!-- **********   [Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Review__c.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Vendor_Product_Review__c.Department__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Review__c.Product__c}"/>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Review__c.Reviewed_Product__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Review__c.Product2__c}" />
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
```

And that's essentially it. Nothing special.

The VF page is included in the Permission Set, so it's nothing weird about that.

I'm at a total loss. Anybody have any ideas ?

Comment: Do you use an `Apex` extensions? Do you specify `with sharing`?

Comment: No extensions - just standard controller for the custom object.

Comment: The VF page is essentially just a bunch of inputfields and pageblocksections.

Comment: If you look at the M/D field setup, is **`Sharing Setting`** set to `Read Only: Allows users with at least Read access to the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records.`?

Comment: I updated my original post to include the VF page code. The OWD for the Master is Public Read Only ; the Detail is Controlled By Parent. There is no other Sharing going on with either objects. Like I said, it all works fine whenever I don't use the VF page. Once I start using the VF page for the edit override in the Detail object everybody is able to edit any of the detail records, including the ones which are Locked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44833/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-zoom-v).